# How to import a networkX graph to neo4j?

Tags: python, neo4j, networkx

I have a graph created with `networkX` and I am using neonx to import it to `neo4j` on localhost. I have a `networkX` type graph called `G`. Below is the code:

```
data1 = json_graph.node_link_data(G)
H = json_graph.node_link_graph(data1)

results = neonx.write_to_neo("http://localhost:7474/db/data/", H, 'LINKS_TO')
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aman/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2961, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-5-0d401e8987b7>", line 31, in <module>
    results = neonx.write_to_neo("http://localhost:7474/db/data/", H, 'LINKS_TO')
  File "/Users/aman/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neonx/neo.py", line 86, in write_to_neo
    batch_url = all_server_urls['batch']
KeyError: 'batch'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that your neo4j instance requires authentication, but neonx doesn't appear to support it.

to disable authentication set: `dbms.security.auth_enabled=false` (see: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/security/authentication-authorization/enable/)

to verify this is the issue point your browser to: http://localhost:7474/db/data/ and see if you are prompted for a user and password

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to dump networkx graph and import it into Neo4j.

Advantages:

- You don't need to have a working connection with Neo4j server
- Dump once and load it anywhere anytime. You have saved version/backup.

Dump networkx graph:

```py
nx.write_graphml(g, 'path/to/file.graphml')
```

Load into Neo4j:

- Install apoc plugin for Neo4j from [here](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures)
- Enable `apoc.import.file.enabled=true` in conf/neo4j.conf
- Place your graph dump `file.graphml` in `import/` folder

```sh
cypher-shell -a bolt://localhost:7687 "call apoc.import.graphml('file.graphml', {})"
```

Or in browser:

```
call apoc.import.graphml('file.graphml', {})
```

For more details:

- [apoc.import](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/import/graphml/)
- [Neo4j Config](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/config/)
- [Networkx export](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/graphml.html)

Comment: When I followed this procedure I did indeed end up with a graph in Neo4j, but it has no labels, and all the edges have been named "RELATED". Did the information loss happen during the export or the import?