# Which elements from networkx graph might become labels at neo4j graph?

Tags: python, neo4j, networkx

I have a MultiDiGraph in networkx and I am thinking about exporting it to neo4j. I have already a property for the nodes called ntype and a property for the edges called dtype which fits with the label concept for nodes and edges for neo4j graphs.

Which elements from networkx might become labels at neo4j? How can it be managed?

I add an example of the graph at python and the graph I would like to get when exporting to neo4j.

Here is the code at python

```
import networkx as nx

G=nx.MultiDiGraph()

G.add_nodes_from([
    (1,{'ntype':'NUMBER', 'color':'blue'}),
    (2,{'ntype':'NUMBER', 'color':'yellow'}),
    ('A',{'ntype':'LETTER', 'state':'done'}),
    ('B',{'ntype':'LETTER', 'state':'pending'})
    ])
G.add_edges_from([
    (1,'A','dir',{'etype':'IMPACTS', 'when':'old'}),
    (1,'A','n_dir',{'etype':'IMPACTS', 'when':'new'}),
    (1,'B','n_dir',{'etype':'ALTS', 'when':'future'}),
    (2,'B','dir',{'etype':'IMPACTS', 'when':'new'}),
    (2,'B','n_dir',{'etype':'IMPACTS', 'when':'old'}),
    (2,'A','n_dir',{'etype':'ALTS', 'when':'new'}),
    ])
```

And here is the code at neo4j of the graph I would like to have when importing from networkx

```
CREATE (one:NUMBER {name:1, color:'blue'})
CREATE (two:NUMBER {name:2, color:'yellow'})
CREATE (A:LETTER {name:'A', state:'done'})
CREATE (B:LETTER {name:'B', state:'pending'})
CREATE (one)-[:IMPACTS {k:'dir', when:'old'}]->(A)
CREATE (one)-[:IMPACTS {k:'n_dir', when:'new'}]->(A)
CREATE (one)-[:IMPACTS {k:'n_dir', when:'future'}]->(B)
CREATE (two)-[:ALTS {k:'dir', when:'new'}]->(B)
CREATE (two)-[:IMPACTS {k:'n_dir', when:'old'}]->(B)
CREATE (two)-[:ALTS {k:'n_dir', when:'new'}]->(A)
```

[image: This is a picture of the the graph]

I have tried exporting in networkx to graphml and importing in neo4j as described here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52210619/how-to-import-a-networkx-graph-to-neo4j). I also added the parameters *readLabels* and *storeNodeIds*. From the browser:

```
CALL apoc.import.graphml("test.graphml", {readLabels: true, storeNodeIds:true})
```

Now I get the labels for the edges but I do not get the labels for the nodes. This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: I have been reading about nxneo4j but it seems that only can creates one label for all the nodes and one label for all the edges using the config file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made some reserch and finally I have got a process to be able to export a networkx graph into a neo4j graph managing the labels.
Some details have to be considered:

1.- **When creating the nodes**: the **property** to become a label at neo4j must be **named as *labels*** (notice that it is in plural, do not ask why, it works). Its value must be a string starting with ':'

```
G.add_nodes_from([(1,{'labels':':NUMBER', 'color':'blue'}), ('A',{'labels':':LETTER', 'state':'done'})])
```

2.- **When creating the edges**: the **property** to become a label at neo4j must be **named as *label*** (now it is in singular!!). Its value must be a string starting with ':'

```
G.add_edges_from([(1,'A','dir',{'label':'IMPACTS', 'when':'old'})])
```

3.- **For MultiDiGraph** the k value is not going to be imported. My workarround is to **duplicate *k* as an edge property** called, for exampel *id*.

```
for u,v,k in G.edges(keys=True):
G[u][v][k]['id']=k
```

4.- Export networkx graph to **graphml** using **named_key_ids=True**

```
nx.write_graphml(G, 'test.graphml', named_key_ids=True)
```

5.- Import to neo4j with parameteres *readLabels: true* and *storeNodeIds:true*. At neo4j browser you might have:

```
CALL apoc.import.graphml("test.graphml", {readLabels: true, storeNodeIds:true})
```

Here I include a graph created in networkx that can be imported to neo4j as described:

```
import networkx as nx

G=nx.MultiDiGraph()

#creation of nodes with property called 'labels'
G.add_nodes_from([
    (1,{'labels':':NUMBER', 'color':'blue'}),
    (2,{'labels':':NUMBER', 'color':'yellow'}),
    ('A',{'labels':':LETTER', 'state':'done'}),
    ('B',{'labels':':LETTER', 'state':'pending'})
    ])
#creation of edges with property called 'label'
G.add_edges_from([
    (1,'A','dir',{'label':'IMPACTS', 'when':'old'}),
    (1,'A','n_dir',{'label':'IMPACTS', 'when':'new'}),
    (1,'B','n_dir',{'label':'ALTS', 'when':'future'}),
    (2,'B','dir',{'label':'IMPACTS', 'when':'new'}),
    (2,'B','n_dir',{'label':'IMPACTS', 'when':'old'}),
    (2,'A','n_dir',{'label':'ALTS', 'when':'new'}),
    ])
#k is duplicated at every node as a property
for u,v,k in G.edges(keys=True):
    G[u][v][k]['id']=k

nx.write_graphml(G, 'test.graphml', named_key_ids=True)
```

What is pending? To figure out how to assing to a node or an edge more than one label. Any help will be welcome

Comment: This was super helpful and the only reference I can find to this challenge.  Anyways, I am using neo4j Desktop and I still cannot get neo4j Bloom to create a perspective with the data even though in the neo4j Browser the graph shows perfectly and Bloom indicates the presence of labels and relationship.  Have you had success with Bloom and if so, how?

Comment: Hello, I have not tried Neo4j Bloom.

Comment: No worries.  The problem was my understanding of Bloom ie. until you create a search/query statement, no perspective is created.  But your post enabled me to create a proper .graphml so really appreciated.

Comment: gem of an answer

Comment: btw, if you want to have multiple labels, you can write :LABEL_1:LABEL2 etc, ie, colon separated